# Creating a Excel document which formats all CSV that comes in same format with a standard styling?

Tags: excel, csv, formatting

I have a lot of CSV files which I created by gathering data from a website. The CSV files  all have the same type of format as they are just different sets of data with the same headers. For example:

`School,Carleton University
School Facts,
SchoolName,Carleton University
Location,"Ottawa, ON"
SchoolType,University
Language,English
Student Count,"24,554 Students"
Student Type,Full-time Undergraduate`

Would be a standard CSV I have where other CSVs would just contain a different entry for things like SchoolName, Location etc.

What I wanted to do was open one of these files and then format it a certain way (ie. highlight certain things like SchoolName row, or things like School Facts to make the document easier to see). I was wondering if its possible I can do it for one and the just import other CSV's and they would automatically be the same way? If it is how do I do it or is there another way I can go about handling the data from the CSV to make it presentable?

Thank you, not sure if I am asking this right as I am new to excel and using CSV's in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your csv, record a new macro in a personal workbook, format your csv, stop recording.

Make sure to select the whole column when you format so if your next csv has more line, the format will still work. Save your macro, and you should be able to run it everytime you open a new file.

Answer (score 1):

You could import it into a tab and have another tab that maps to all the fields in the tab you import to, and make the 2nd tab formatted however you like.

Also check out conditional formatting for things like highlighting things that meet certain criteria.